# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity, gui, text, objects

Hi so im displaying food, health an water on the screen in a text box by using UnityEngine.UI and making text variables. They are all defined in the update function so they will keep changing and are all defined one after another with nothing in between. it will only call the first one there and the others it gives me the error message above.

Comment: Can you give a code sample, or any additional detail? This isn't informative at all.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: _italic_**bold** `Update_Food();
        Update_health();
        Update_Water();`

Comment: And this is the health update function                                                              public void Update_health()
    {
        HealthDisplay.text = ("Health: " + Health);
    }

Comment: And the food and water is exactly the same as that but obviously with a different variable . When I execute them in the void update it will only do the first one called and the rest will get that error and will not be shown on screen but the first one will. It needs to update every frame obvoiusly so it will update on screen.